# Spring-boot REST security config roles don't work right

Tags: rest, http, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

Just users with admin role should be able to make a request at "users/all", but the basic users are able too.
This is my security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers( "/users/all").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/users/me").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "BASIC_USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

[This is the request from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF0OF.png)

Why i am able to make the request with the basic user?

if i put them in this order:

```
.antMatchers( "/users/all").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
 .antMatchers("/users/me").authenticated().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "BASIC_USER")
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").permitAll()
```

It's the same thing, but the /me request don't work anymore.

[/all request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHTj5.png)
[/me request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyzWw.png)

Now /me request response is 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return this.user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(String.format("ROLE_%s", role.getRole()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

i changed **role** to **role.getRole()**

Answer (score -1):

Can you change the lines, that admin restriction is upper?

Comment: I have the same problem.